# Python Pandas: Inconsistent behaviour of boolean indexing on a Series using the len() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Series of strings and I need to apply boolean indexing using `len()` on it.

In one case it works, in another case it does not:

The working case is a `groupby` on a dataframe, followed by a `unique()` on the resulting Series and a `apply(str)` to change the resulting `numpy.ndarray` entries into strings:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],'B':[1,2,2,3,4,5,4,4]})
dg = df.groupby('A')['B'].unique().apply(str)
db = dg[len(dg) > 2]
```

This just works fine and yields the desired result:

```
>>db
Out[119]: '[1 2 3]'
```

The following however throws `KeyError: True`:

```
ss = pd.Series(['a','b','cc','dd','eeee','ff','ggg'])
ls = ss[len(ss) > 2]
```

Both objects `dg` and `ss` are just Series of Strings:

```
>>type(dg)
Out[113]: pandas.core.series.Series

>>type(ss)
Out[114]: pandas.core.series.Series

>>type(dg['a'])
Out[115]: str

>>type(ss[0])
Out[116]: str
```

I'm following the syntax as described in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

I can see a potential conflict because `len(ss)` on its own returns the length of the Series itself and now that exact command is used for boolean indexing `ss[len(ss) > 2]`, but then I'd expect neither of the two examples to work.

Right now this behaviour seems inconsistent, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html), because need length of each value of `Series`:

```
ss = pd.Series(['a','b','cc','dd','eeee','ff','ggg'])

print (ss.str.len())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    4
5    2
6    3
dtype: int64

print (ss.str.len() > 2)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

ls = ss[ss.str.len() > 2]
print (ls)
4    eeee
6     ggg
dtype: object
```

If use `len`, get length of `Series`:

```
print (len(ss))
7
```

Another solution is [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `len`:

```
ss = pd.Series(['a','b','cc','dd','eeee','ff','ggg'])
ls = ss[ss.apply(len) > 2]
print (ls)
4    eeee
6     ggg
dtype: object
```

First script is wrong, you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `len` also:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],'B':[1,2,2,2,4,5,4,6]})
dg = df.groupby('A')['B'].unique()
print (dg)
A
a       [1, 2]
b    [4, 5, 6]
Name: B, dtype: object

db = dg[dg.apply(len) > 2]
print (db)
A
b    [4, 5, 6]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

If cast list to `str`, you get another `len` (`length` of data + length of `[]` + length of whitespaces):

```
dg = df.groupby('A')['B'].unique().apply(str)
print (dg)
A
a      [1 2]
b    [4 5 6]
Name: B, dtype: object

print (dg.apply(len))
A
a    5
b    7
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, that works with both. Can you explain why the first example is working if it's wrong as well?

Comment: Yes, I get another solution which works with first code.

Comment: First code is wrong, if change `df` to `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],'B':[1,2,2,3,4,5,4,6]})` it doesnt return both rows.

Comment: You have such data in first script, which return alhough good result, but if change it, it works bad. so is necessary change solution. Please see last edit.